# How to solve selenium exception: StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache

Tags: selenium

I'm getting collection of links. Then I click first link, do something, moving back (`driver.navigate().back();`), getting second link and then `link.click();` throws an exception `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you navigate away from the page the element variables become invalid. The trick is to find the first element, click, go back and **then** find the second element and click.